# Clarification needed regarding Javascript's keydown event and jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom-events, keydown

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("#someTextInputID").keydown(function(event){
 console.log(event.keyCode);
 console.log("input_box.val(): "+input_box.val());
 console.log("input_box.val().length: "+input_box.val().length);
})
```

What puzzles me is that if I type in "750", three keyCodes are logged but I also get this in my console after having typed the string above:

> input_box.val(): 75
>
> input_box.val().length: 2

What happens then with the last character i.e. "0"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simple, the last key pressed is not in the `.value` of an `input` until the `keyup` event.

The order of events when pressing a key is:

1. `keydown` (fires at most once per key press, key is available in `event.which`, but not in `.value`)
2. `keypress` (fires at least once per key press (e.g. if you hold the key down), key is available in `event.which`, but not in `.value`)
3. `keyup` (fires at most once per key press, key is available in `event.which`, **and**  in `.value`)

You can detect which key was pressed during the `keydown` or `keypress` phase by examining the [`which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property of the `Event` object, and using the [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method.

Another useful trick you can employ is to use `setTimeout`,  but pass a value of `0` as the delay. A delay of `0` adds the callback to the back of the callstack, which delays the execution long enough for the `.value` to update.:

```
$("#someTextInputID").keydown(function(event){
    var that = this;

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(that.value); // will record value
    }, 0);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$("#someTextInputID").keyup(function(event){
 console.log(event.keyCode);
 console.log("input_box.val(): "+input_box.val());
 console.log("input_box.val().length: "+input_box.val().length);
})
```